# When coping baseboard do I cut the top edge square?

Tags: technique, cutting

I'm replacing the baseboard, having laid new flooring, and am coping the inside corners. However, I'm finding I tend to break that very thin "point" on the top - either while cutting it, or when fitting to the wall.

[image]

Should I just cut it off square? And if so, do I still back cut right to the top as that would show up?

Comment: Hard to say. This might veer a little to DIY.SE. Though, trim was often the purview of fine carpentry historically.

Comment: I can repost to DIY if you'd prefer ... I tend to think hand-tools = woodworking

Comment: Just checked DIY and the question is over there either (not much on coping at all actually)

Comment: meant to say "isn't over there", not "is"

Comment: I would continue to cut the miter but be more careful when handling it so that I don't break it.  If I did break it, I would save the piece and stick it back on with a little wood glue.  Also, these types of "features" can sometimes be hidden with a little caulk.

Comment: Yes, cut it back square so that the very top of the joint looks like a butt joint. That should take care of a lot of that fuzzing. The roughness in the first place might be due to a dull miter saw blade, not enough teeth, or cutting the top of the base against the fence.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate sounds like that can be made into an answer (if we have decided to keep it here.)

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate Sounds good. FYI I'm only using a power saw to cut the original 45 degree. The actual coping is done with a coping saw. The roughness is caused when the point breaks off.

Comment: Just to clarify, *are* you coping here? Coping is undercutting the back face of the joint so that pretty much only the leading edge contacts the mating piece.

Comment: "do I still back cut right to the top" <-- @Graphus, I'd say so...

Comment: @Graphus Yes, I am coping, with a coping saw and not a jigsaw or other power tool. With the baseboard I'm using, if I scrupulously cope the profile I am left with a paper thin triangular point at the very top of the board which looks like it should go "over" the top of the butt cut piece. It is so fragile that it breaks off when I try and fit the piece into the corner, leaving what you see above.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Since this is essentially the norm for a true coped joint like this, following a guide or guides found online to the letter may help here — in essence I think it amounts to coping this portion at a less acute angle, so the wood is better supported at this weakest point.

Comment: @Graphus If I could have found an online guide which dealt with this particular bit ... :)

Comment: I haven't looked at anything related to coping in quite a while, but my recollection is that the general way it's done is to do as described and not use the same angle slavishly for the whole thing. But that said, my gut it telling me that a gentler touch may be all that's required. It'll slow the work down, but far less than the breakage and any subsequent repair or re-do work.

Comment: as this is still up (hasn't been closed as "off topic") .. the comment from Aloysius about cutting the top square was actually the solution. Once I got that part down, I was generally cutting the copes correctly first time every time - and I've replaced about 400 ft of baseboard now. so, if he wants to turn this into an answer I'd like to accept it.

Comment: @kdopen since Aloysius hasn't opted to post an answer, feel free to do so. Credit him in your answer if you'd like. Make sure you click the check mark as soon as the system will allow you to, too!

Comment: @FreeMan Done now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual answer was provided in a comment to the question:

> Yes, cut it back square so that the very top of the joint looks like a butt joint. That should take care of a lot of that fuzzing. [...] – Aloysius Defenestrate Jun 8 '20 at 2:31

This was never clear in the videos I watched.

Once I got that part down, I was generally cutting the copes correctly first time every time - and I've replaced about 400 ft of baseboard now.

Answer (score 0):

Specifically regarding the blowout of the wood fibers, regardless of the angle being cut you could apply some masking tape ("blue tape") to that portion, rather tightly. This often will help support the fibers as the cut penetrates the last portion.